# In Redux, replace dispatch in action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

Given my action creator:

```
export const REQUEST_ARTICLES = 'REQUEST_ARTICLES'
export const RECEIVE_ARTICLES = 'RECEIVE_ARTICLES'
export const CHANGE_PAGE = 'CHANGE_PAGE'

export const changePage = (currentPage) => ({
    type: CHANGE_PAGE,
    currentPage,
})

export const requestArticles = () => ({
    type: REQUEST_ARTICLES,
})

export const receiveArticles = json => ({
    type: RECEIVE_ARTICLES,
    posts: json.hits,
})

export const fetchArticles = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await dispatch(requestArticles())
        let response = await fetch('www.abc.com')
        let json = await response.json()
        await dispatch(receiveArticles(json))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error:', e)
    }
}
```

So I am using dispatch inside action creator. But if I have to dispatch multiple actions, then my code would be

```
        try {
            await dispatch(requestArticles1())
            await dispatch(requestArticles2())
            await dispatch(requestArticles3())
            await dispatch(requestArticles4())
            await dispatch(requestArticles5())
            let response = await fetch('www.abc.com')
            let json = await response.json()
            await dispatch(receiveArticles(json))
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error:', e)
        }
```

I already use `mapDispatchToProps` in the component. Is there any similar way/method I can use in action creator so that I don't have to dispatch actions manually one by one?

Comment: You may consider a library like `redux-saga`. It handles asynchronous actions wonderfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redux's `store.dispatch()` is not an asynchronous function, so there is no need to `await` its return.  It will still work because `await`ing non-async functions casts them to an immediately-resolving promise.

With regard to dispatching multiple actions, you will need to manually dispatch every action that you need.  The question becomes: why do you need to dispatch so many actions?  In general for an ajax-calling thunk you will use a started, succeeded and failed action, and not many more.

```
export const fetchArticles = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(requestArticlesStarted())
        const response = await fetch('www.abc.com')
        const json = await response.json()
        dispatch(requestArticlesSucceeded(json))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error:', e);
        dispatch(requestArticlesFailed(e));
    }
}
```